# Call method and draw

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 classes witch inherit another class called `ParentClass` and each of the 3 has the following code inside

```
public void DrawBackground(Graphics e, Rectangle rect)
{
    e.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, rect);
}
```

In my main form i have a variable like this `ParentClass PClass = new OneOfTheThreeClasses`

How can i call the `DrawBAckground` method of those classes using that variable, from my form's paint event?

Comment: Learn about virtual methods.

Comment: Do you realize that calling such a method on another class, passing in the `Graphics` and `Rectangle`, will only result in the calling form being painted?

Comment: @adv12 Yes i know that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create either an abstract or virtual method on `ParentClass`.  Something like this:

```
public virtual void DrawBackground(Graphics e, Rectangle rect)
{
    // do nothing
}
```

Then in the child classes, override that method:

```
public override void DrawBackground(Graphics e, Rectangle rect)
{
    e.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, rect);
}
```

The idea is that `ParentClass` needs to define the operations which can be performed on it or any polymorphic version of it (such as a child type).  It doesn't necessarily have to provide an implementation (and the definition can be abstract or virtual depending on how `ParentClass` itself is implemented and used), but does need to "know" about the method in some way in order for anything to be able to invoke it on an instance of `ParentClass`.

Comment: Thanks, i just checked msdn, it turns out that a lot of methods in VS are virtual, so they can be overridden again and again..